# Remove the need to use out-file only to import the file immediately using PowerShell just to convert the base type

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to turn the file below into one that contains no comments '#', no blank lines, no unneeded spaces, and only one entry per line.  I'm unsure how to run the following code without the need to output the file and then reimport it.  There should be code that doesn't require that step but I can't find it.  The way I wrote my script also doesn't look right to me even though it works.  As if there was a more elegant way of doing what I'm attempting but I just don't see it.

Before File Change:  TNSNames.ora

```
#Created 9_27_16
#Updated 8_30_19

AAAA.world=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST = 
        (ADDRESS = 
          (COMMUNITY = tcp.world)
          (PROTOCOL = TCP)
          (Host = www.url1111.com)
          (Port = 1111)
        )
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = SID1111)
    )
  )
  
#Created 9_27_16

BBBB.world=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=tcp.world)(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=url2222.COM)(Port=2222))(ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=tcp.world)(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=url22222.COM)(Port=22222)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SID2222)))
CCCC.world=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=url3333.COM)(Port=3333))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SID3333)))
DDDD.url       =(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=tcp.world)(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=URL4444   )(Port=4444))(ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=TCP.world)(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=URL44444   )(Port=44444)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SID4444   )(GLOBAL_NAME=ASDF.URL)))

#Created 9_27_16
#Updated 8_30_19
```

After File Change:

```
AAAA.world=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=tcp.world)(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=www.url1111.com)(Port=1111)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SID1111)))
BBBB.world=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=tcp.world)(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=url2222.COM)(Port=2222))(ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=tcp.world)(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=url22222.COM)(Port=22222)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SID2222)))
CCCC.world=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=url3333.COM)(Port=3333))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SID3333)))
DDDD.url=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=tcp.world)(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=URL4444)(Port=4444))(ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=TCP.world)(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=URL44444)(Port=44444)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SID4444)(GLOBAL_NAME=ASDF.URL)))
```

Code:

```
# Get the file
[System.IO.FileInfo] $File = 'C:\temp\TNSNames.ora'
[string] $data = (Get-Content $File.FullName | Where-Object { !$_.StartsWith('#') }).ToUpper()

# Convert the data.  This part is where any (CONNECT_DATA entry ends up on it's own line.
$Results = $data.Replace(" ", "").Replace("`t", "").Replace(")))", ")))`n")

# Convert $Results from BaseType of System.Object to System.Array
$Path = '.\.vscode\StringResults.txt'
$Results | Out-File -FilePath $Path
$Results = Get-Content $Path

# Find all lines that start with '(CONNECT_DATA'
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Results.Length - 1; $i++) {
  if ($Results[$i + 1].StartsWith("(CONNECT_DATA")) {
    # Add the '(CONNECT_DATA' line to the previous line
    $Results[$i] = $Results[$i] + $Results[$i + 1]
    # Blank out the '(CONNECT_DATA' line
    $Results[$i + 1] = ''
  }
}

# Remove all blank lines
$FinalForm = $null
foreach ($Line in $Results) {
  if ($Line -ne "") {
    $FinalForm += "$Line`n"
  }
}
$FinalForm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the crux of your problem is that you have declared $data as a [string] which is fine because probably some of your replace operations work better as a single string.  Its just that $Results also then ends up  being a string so when you try to index into $Results near the bottom these operations fail.  You can however easily turn your $Results variable into a string array using the -split operator  this would eliminate the need to save the string to disk and import back in just to accomplish the same.  See comments below.

```
# Get the file
[System.IO.FileInfo] $File = 'C:\temp\TNSNames.ora'
[string] $data = (Get-Content $File.FullName | Where-Object { !$_.StartsWith('#') }).ToUpper()

# Convert the data.  This part is where any (CONNECT_DATA entry ends up on it's own line.
$Results = $data.Replace(' ', '').Replace("`t", '').Replace(')))', ")))`n")

# You do not need to do this next section.  Essentially this is just saving your multiline string 
# to a file and then using Get-Content to read it back in as a string array

    # Convert $Results from BaseType of System.Object to System.Array
    # $Path = 'c:\temp\StringResults.txt'
    # $Results | Out-File -FilePath $Path
    # $Results = Get-Content $Path

# Instead split your $Results string into multiple lines using -split
# this will do the same thing as above without writing to file
$Results = $Results -split "\r?\n"

# Find all lines that start with '(CONNECT_DATA'
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Results.Length - 1; $i++) {
    if ($Results[$i + 1].StartsWith('(CONNECT_DATA')) {
        # Add the '(CONNECT_DATA' line to the previous line
        $Results[$i] = $Results[$i] + $Results[$i + 1]
        # Blank out the '(CONNECT_DATA' line
        $Results[$i + 1] = ''
    }
}

# Remove all blank lines
$FinalForm = $null
foreach ($Line in $Results) {
    if ($Line -ne '') {
        $FinalForm += "$Line`n"
    }
}
$FinalForm
```

Also, for fun, try this out

```
((Get-Content 'C:\temp\tnsnames.ora' |
        Where-Object {!$_.StartsWith('#') -and ![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)}) -join '' -replace '\s' -replace '\)\s?\)\s?\)', ")))`n" -replace '\r?\n\(Connect_data','(connect_data').ToUpper()
```

Comment: Your "For Fun" method works great.  But I found an outlier in one of the files I need to convert.  How would you update the "For Fun" line to also account the (') from this entry?  When I run your command there is a new line starting with the 2nd (').

Beq-Local.world = 
(DESCRIPTION = 
(ADDRESS_LIST = 
(ADDRESS = 
(COMMUNITY = beq.world)
(PROTOCOL = BEQ)
(PROGRAM = oracle73)
(ARGV0 = oracle73ORCL)
(ARGS = '(DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))')
)
)
(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = ORCL)
)
)

Comment: I figured it out.  ((Get-Content $File | Where-Object { !$_.StartsWith('#') -and ![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) }) -join '' -replace '\s' -replace '\)\s?\)\s?\)', ")))`n" -replace '\r?\n\(Connect_data', '(connect_data' -replace "\r?\n\'", "'").ToUpper()